# How can i save changed data from RecyclerView and upload the changes

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I am processing an *image* and getting 'data' from it. Then i show those in **RecyclerView**. I correct some data in **RecyclerView** if necessary. How to upload the corrected data with all the rest, Because even if the correction shows in RecyclerView it is not uploading the change ,Rather mistaken data are being uploaded. Can someone please help i am stuck for several days...

This is part of my mainActivity where i am adding the data to **Recyclerview**?

TextExtractionActivity.class

```
if (fileDirectory.isDirectory()) {
    listCroppedImages.clear();
    EmptyViewCroppedImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    RVCroppedImages.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    listCroppedImages.clear();
    String PhotoPath[] = new String[100];
    final String StudentMatric[] = new String[100];
    final String AttendanceRecord[] = new String[100];

    for (int i = 1; i <= fileDirectory.listFiles().length; i++) {
        PhotoPath[i] = croppedImageDirectory + i + ".jpg";

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap croppedimageold = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(PhotoPath[i], options);
        Bitmap croppedimagenew = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(croppedimageold, 460, 66, true);

        StudentMatric[i] = TextImageProcess(croppedimagenew);
        AttendanceRecord[i] = CircleDetection(croppedimagenew, StudentMatric[i]);
        listCroppedImages.add(new CroppedImageModel(String.valueOf(i), PhotoPath[i], StudentMatric[i], AttendanceRecord[i]));

        btnUploadAttendance.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                for (int x = 1; x <= listCroppedImages.size(); x++) {
                    UploadData(StudentMatric[x], AttendanceRecord[x], x);
                }
            }
        });


    }
} else {
    EmptyViewCroppedImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    RVCroppedImages.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

-----------------------------------------------------------------------

public void UploadData(final String StudentMatric, final String AttendanceRecord, final int x) {
     ProgressUploadAttendance.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    Query query = StudentsRef.orderByKey().equalTo(StudentMatric);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
              int progress = x / listCroppedImages.size() * 100;
              DatabaseReference StudentMatricRef = StudentsRef.child(StudentMatric).child("Attendance").push();
              StudentMatricRef.child("Status").setValue(AttendanceRecord);
              StudentMatricRef.child("Date").setValue(getCurrentDate());
              ProgressUploadAttendance.setProgress(progress);
          } else {
              Toast.makeText(TextExtractionActivity.this, "Could not Find " + StudentMatric, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }

      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
          throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
      }
  });

}
```

"RecyclerViewAdapterCroppedImages.class"

```
class RecyclerViewAdapterCroppedImages extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapterCroppedImages.CroppedimageViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<CroppedImageModel> mData;
int x =0;

//   private String StudentMatric, studentMatric, AttendanceStatus, attendanceStatus;

public RecyclerViewAdapterCroppedImages() { }   //Constructor


public RecyclerViewAdapterCroppedImages(Context mContext, List<CroppedImageModel> mData) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mData = mData;
}


@Override
public CroppedimageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View croppedimageview;
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    croppedimageview = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_cropped_image, parent, false);
    return new CroppedimageViewHolder(croppedimageview);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final CroppedimageViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap croppedimageold = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mData.get(position).getCroppedImagePath(), options);
    Bitmap croppedimagenew = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(croppedimageold, 528, 80, true);


    holder.StudentNo.setText(mData.get(position).getStudentNo());
    holder.CroppedImage.setImageBitmap(croppedimagenew);
    holder.StudentId.setText(mData.get(position).getStudentMatric());
    holder.StudentStatus.setText(mData.get(position).getAttendanceRecord());

    holder.StudentStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mData.get(position).getAttendanceRecord().equals("Failed")) {
                holder.StudentStatus.setText("Present");
            } else if (mData.get(position).getAttendanceRecord().equals("Present")) {
                holder.StudentStatus.setText("Absent");
            } else if (mData.get(position).getAttendanceRecord().equals("Absent")) {
                holder.StudentStatus.setText("Present");
            }
        }
    });


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}


class CroppedimageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView StudentNo, StudentId, StudentStatus;
    ImageView CroppedImage;

    private CroppedimageViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        StudentNo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvtxtprocessstudentno);
        CroppedImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivcroppedimage);
        StudentId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvtxtprocessstudentid);
        StudentStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvtxtprocessstudentstatus);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: What is happening when you are using this code?

Comment: when i correct the processed data in RecyclerView by tapping the textview it gets corrected or atleast shows the change in the view. but the corrected version is not uploaded to firebase when i press  btnUploadAttendance. rather uploading the processed version in the main TextExtractionActivity.class

Comment: When you are pressing the `btnUploadAttendance` button you aren't setting any value in your database at all. What specifically in your code is doing something different than what you expected?

Comment: i think, its uploading the data fine since i check the data in my firebase and cross check with the processed value. it get added all the time.

Comment: and i just use one of the two processed value to cross check with the parent field. and the other data gets stored as expected. the problem is before uploading the data if i make any correction, it wont correct the actual data that is being processed.. for example :  AttendanceRecord[10] it contains a value "Present". so if i press upload it gets uploaded. but if i change the value into "Absent" by tapping on the text on RecyclerView , the data on the holder shows "absent" but upload the initial value which was "Present" at the first place and vise versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The thing is i thought i have to notifiyOnDatachange by adapter which located in my main activity. but i did not have to..

in my RecyclerViewAdapterCroppedImage.class

```
final CroppedImageModel changedRecord = mData.get(position);
holder.IVattendance.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (mData.get(position).getAttendanceRecord())
            {
                case "Failed":
                    mData.get(position).setAttendanceRecord("Present");
                    correctionAttendance(position, changedRecord);//code
                    break;

                case "Present":
                    mData.get(position).setAttendanceRecord("Absent");
                    correctionAttendance(position, changedRecord);
                    break;

                case "Absent":
                    mData.get(position).setAttendanceRecord("Present");
                    correctionAttendance(position, changedRecord);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

    public void correctionAttendance(int position, CroppedImageModel attendanceRecord ) {
    mData.set(position, attendanceRecord);
    notifyItemChanged(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

and in my TextExtractionActivity.class i fetch the data directly from Adapter rather than where i am processing and sending the data to Adapter.

```
btnUploadAttendance.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                for (int x = 0; x < listCroppedImages.size(); x++) {
                    UploadData(listCroppedImages.get(x).getStudentMatric(),listCroppedImages.get(x).getAttendanceRecord(),x);
                }
            }
        });
```

and lastly my UploadData() remain same as stated in the question.. 
Thank you anyone who intend to answer or provide format correction..